# How I can divide two statement in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

```
<?php
     $q2 = "SELECT SUM(crd)
           FROM coe_courses
           INNER JOIN student_record ON coe_courses.course_number = 
            student_record.course_number WHERE student_record.id =".$_SESSION['user_id'] ;
     $result = mysqli_query($con , $q2 ) ;
     if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
         echo $row["SUM(crd)"];
     }
     $q2a = "SELECT SUM(points) FROM student_record where student_record.id =".$_SESSION['user_id'] ;
     $result = mysqli_query($con , $q2a ) ;
     if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
       echo $row["SUM(points)"];
     }
?>
```

I wrote this code but how I can make division for those statements at the end of this code

```
echo $row["SUM(crd)"] /$row["SUM(points)"];
```

Comment: $n = (int) ($row["SUM(crd)"] / $row["SUM(points)"]);

Comment: what's output of your code ?

Comment: Store your results in variable then do your calculations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should store those two values in different variables because as per your code you are overriding the $row variable so you will get only second result. After that you can simply do this.

```
if(!empty($b)) {
   $ans = (int) ($a/$b);
}
```

Comment: Well done.This is correct. Make sure you check for divisible by zero

Comment: @ReaganGallant Thanks for suggestion. Indeed it is very important to check division by zero.